# ¿ que es un observable y cuándo usarlo?

Tags: nodejs, angular, observable, programacion-asincrona

antes de pasar por acá creanme que he leído numerosos post sobres observables para tratar de entender que son y por que se usan, sobre todo en Angular que es en lo que me encuentro trabajando actualmente pero aún tengo muchas dudas. Según lo que he entendido, un Observable, se usa para trabajar con un flujo de datos, y que se emiten eventos que uno luego puedo procesar, a través de un observador, por ahí creo que va la idea, pero también creo que se usa para tareas asíncronas, por lo que he visto. además también tengo dudas con su sintaxis, ya que he visto que se definen de varias maneras. Además, también quisiera saber cuál sería la diferencia **(con palabras fáciles de entender, si es posible)** con las promesas, y cuándo se usaría uno u otro. Por ejemplo, encontré este tutorial para enviar un pequeño formulario al Backend: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/angular-9-http-post-node-express-example/ , en dicho tutorial están estos 2 métodos:

```js
  register(user: User): Observable<JwtResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.post<JwtResponse>(`${this.AUTH_SERVER}/register`, user).pipe(
      tap((res:  JwtResponse ) => {

        if (res.user) {
          localStorage.set("ACCESS_TOKEN", res.user.access_token);
          localStorage.set("EXPIRES_IN", res.user.expires_in);
          this.authSubject.next(true);
        }
      })

    );
  }
  
  
  
  
    singIn(user: User): Observable<JwtResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.AUTH_SERVER}/login`, user).pipe(
      tap(async (res: JwtResponse) => {

        if (res.user) {
          localStorage.setItem("ACCESS_TOKEN", res.user.access_token);
          localStorage.setItem("EXPIRES_IN", res.user.expires_in);
          this.authSubject.next(true);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Son casi iguales, veo que ambos devuelven un observable, por que lo hacen así ? que pasaría si no devolvieran un observable ? yo se que los métodos de la clase httpClient **(post, get, etc)** devuelven un observable, pero es necesario que la función que los envuelve devuelva un observable ? además, en el segundo método **(singIn)** usan la palabra **Async** , se que eso es para funciones asíncronas, sinceramente no se si equivocaron, ya que en el primer método que es casi igual no la usaron, pero no se por que razón la colocaron, si según lo que he entendido un observable ya es asíncrono, no sería como colocar algo asíncrono dentro de otra cosa asíncrona ? Sinceramente tengo muchas mas dudas, pero si las coloco todas mi pregunta sería mucho mas larga, estoy tratando de seguir ese tutorial y cada vez que leo una línea se me complica, busco información y no me queda claro. Estaría enormemente agradecido si alguien con experiencia en este tema me aclarara estas dudas y con palabras no tan técnicas. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Según lo que he entendido, un Observable, se usa para trabajar con un
>   flujo de datos, y que se emiten eventos que uno luego puedo procesar,
>   a través de un observador

Eso es correcto.

> pero también creo que se usa para tareas asíncronas

Los observables son asíncronos. Ese flujo de datos que mencionas antes es asíncrono, quiere decir que no se sabe en qué momento el observable emitirá un valor.

> también tengo dudas con su sintaxis, ya que he visto que se definen de
>   varias maneras.

Responder eso sería complicado ya que la definición depende del uso que se le dará. Lo importante es tener claro el concepto.

> quisiera saber cuál sería la diferencia con las promesas

Las promesas también son para trabajar con datos asíncronos. La diferencia es que las promesas solo devuelven un valor y terminan. Los observables pueden emitir muchos valores. Los observables pueden tener muchos observadores así cuando se emite un valor todos pueden recibirlo.

> yo se que los métodos de la clase httpClient (post, get, etc)
>   devuelven un observable, pero es necesario que la función que los
>   envuelve devuelva un observable

Depende, en los ejemplos, las funciones retornan un observable así que se convierten en funciones observables. Por qué lo hacen así? para que el código sea reutilizable. Al retornar un observable esa función puede ser consumida en cualquier lugar de la aplicación y tener muchos suscriptores a la espera que se emita un evento.

> que pasaría si no devolvieran un observable ?

Se tendría que colocar dentro de la función el código para manejar los eventos. Eso llevaría  a un código que no es reutilizable y difícil de mantener.

> en el segundo método (singIn) usan la palabra Async , se que eso es para funciones asíncronas, sinceramente no se si equivocaron, ya que en el primer método que es casi igual no la usaron, pero no se por que razón la colocaron,

El por qué lo pusieron me parece un error ya que no se usa un await, en todo caso no afecta la ejecución del programa.

> si según lo que he entendido un observable ya es asíncrono, no sería como colocar algo asíncrono dentro de otra cosa asíncrona ?

No, son cosas diferentes. En JS existen los operadores `async/await` la función de estos es trabajar con promesas de una manera más clara.  [Referencia](https://javascript.info/async-await)

> si en las funciones, simplemente retornara directamente lo que me devuelve el método post, no estaría retornando un observable de igual forma (el observable de la petición post) ?

Sí. Pero en el ejemplo, el autor del código hace un proceso cuando el observable emite un valor:

```
tap((res:  JwtResponse ) => {

        if (res.user) {
          localStorage.set("ACCESS_TOKEN", res.user.access_token);
          localStorage.set("EXPIRES_IN", res.user.expires_in);
          this.authSubject.next(true);
        }
      })
```

Por esa razón usa los operadores `pipe()` y `tap()`. Ese proceso es a criterio del programador según el problema que intenta resolver. En otros casos podría devolver directamente el observable de la respuesta post y en otros hacer otros procesos diferentes.

Agregando, el operador `tap()` devuelve un observable idéntico al original. Así que para los suscriptores el valor emitido no ha sido modificado.

> se ejcuta la petición post y ésta devuelve un resultado, ese resultado (de tipo JwtResponse) luego entra a la tubería (pipe) y se procesa con el operador Tap (por eso colocan res: JwtResponse), y este operador devuelve un observable que viene siendo el que se retorna en el método register ?

Es correcto.

> he visto que al final a veces suelen un poner un .subscribe()

El método `subscribe()` se usa para agregar un suscriptor al observable. Importante saber que si un observable no tiene suscriptores no emite valores.

> no sé por qué no lo usan en la petición post.

No lo usan porque no se están suscribiendo en ese momento, solo están definiendo lo que se hará cuando se emita un valor. Algo así:

alguien se suscribe al observable -> el observable emite un valor -> ese valor pasa por el `pipe()` `tap()` -> el valor llega al suscriptor.

Comment: Hola @Crrlos , ante todo muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder. Entendí casi todo lo que me dijiste, excepto aquí: si en las functiones, simplemente retornara directamente lo que me devuelve el método post, no estaría retornando un observable de igual forma (el observable de la petición post) ?

Comment: Lo agregué a la respuesta para más claridad.

Comment: El orden de ejecución sería así: se ejcuta la petición post y ésta devuelve un resultado, ese resultado (de tipo JwtResponse) luego entra a la tubería (pipe) y se procesa con el operador Tap (por eso colocan res: JwtResponse), y este operador devuelve un observable que viene siendo el que se retorna en el método register ? disculpa, pero también me pierdo en la ejecución, he visto que al final a veces suelen un poner un .subscribe y no entiendo por que? yo veo al subscribe como lo que se usa para poder obtener el resultado de un observable, por ejemplo, no se xq no lo usan en la petición post.

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Oye amigo muchas gracias, siento que estoy un poco más claro, aunque seguramente en cuestión de minutos me surgirán otras dudas. Puede escribirte por acá, si no es mucha molestia? Se nota que tienes bastante conocimiento sobre el tema en cuestión.

Comment: Sí claro, puedes unirte al chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106331/observable-questions

Comment: Hola amigo, hace rato escribí en ese chat, pero nadie respondió.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106351/discussion-between-crrlos-and-julianprog).